# Massive upload to Google Drive ( 500 GB)

Tags: software-recommendation, google-drive

Do you know any software for Ubuntu, that I could upload a large quantity of GB...I need to make a backup of 500 GB with some files with more than 10 GB....

I only find Windows software and I've to pay for most of them...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have that much space on your Google Drive account?

Comment: If i didnt have that space i wouldnt ask...dont you think ? ;) I have an account with unlimited space....

Comment: Have a look at `rclone`.

Comment: @N0rbert It isnt a duplicate. I need a solution that could be a Google Drive client but also a ftp client, browser plugin or whatever....And the duplicate doesnt work as i could read is abandonware or dead projects....

Comment: **Eduardo:** the duplicate is an answer: all recent versions of Ubuntu are mentioned there (don't just read the accepted answer but all the highly voted answers)